# Why did a group of swimmers stay in one place in The Meg?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, the-meg

Near the end of *The Meg*, thousands of visitors are in the waters of Sanya Bay. Most are floating in colorful inner tubes. When they spot the giant shark, nearly all of them swim towards the beach in a panic. However, a group of about 50 stay clustered together without swimming towards the shore.  The aerial shot looks like this:

[image]

Why did everyone in that group refuse to swim to shore? They were strangers, as shown by the one kid who nagged his mom to go swimming; he didn't know any of them. If it was just a group of strangers who couldn't swim strongly enough to get to shore, it doesn't make sense that they would have all been in one place. If the Meg had separated them from the rest of the group, some of them would have swum for shore when the Meg passed. **Is there an in-universe explanation for the group staying where they are?**

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen the movie, but this sounds somewhat plausible and actually a good strategy:

- If you're in that group in open water, would you really try to swim to the beach, knowing the shark is between you and the beach?
- Most shark attacks against humans are the result of the shark confusing the human with potential prey.A lone swimmer or surfer fits into the pattern for prey a lot better. A large group clumped together however does not. The fish might even have a hard time identifying them as individuals.

Comment: It appears that you watch Shark Week ;)

Comment: And beside those could be the fifty swimmers who are too stunned and shocked by a Megalodon attack - nobody who willingly goes in the ocean expects a Megalodon attack (& vice versa) - to make up their minds what to do.

Comment: Plus, doesn't activity/movement also attracts a shark's attention?